# jQuery hide all elements without class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, if-statement

I have a simple bit of jQuery which toggles the class "active" to an li once clicked:

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

What I then want to happen is have every other li in the list hidden (display: none) then when you click the active li again it removes the active class but sets all other li's to be visible again too. This is what I am struggling to achieve.

I've tried using an if statement within the click function to check if the "active" class exists and if it does setting all li's to hidden, and if it doesn't then setting the css to show them again, but this doesn't work.

Edit:

tilz0R's answer was almost what I was looking for, I just modified it slightly to suit my needs.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

The hidden class simply has display: none, so that all other li's are hidden apart from the one that was clicked, and then all are shown again on the second click of the active li.

Comment: Can we have some working minimal example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find siblings of current `li` element.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: This almost works, but the other li's aren't showing again once it is clicked a second time

Comment: Idk what your result really should be, but maybe `.toggle()` instead of `.hide()` can do the job. @Edward1442

Answer (score 0):

When you click any `<li>` tag, the all `<li>` tag will be hidden except selected `<li>`. And again click, then all `<li>` tag will show and remove the active class.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>first</li>
  <li>second</li>
  <li>third</li>
  <li>forth</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
    jQuery('ul li').click(function() {
      if(jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
        jQuery('ul li:not(".active")').show();
      } else {
        jQuery('ul li').removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active');
        jQuery('ul li:not(".active")').hide();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `addClass`, `removeClass` and `show()` / `hide()`

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('li').show();
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('li').hide();
    $(this).addClass('active').show();
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ol>
```